# Getting undefined variable using isset

Tags: php, forms

Using the following code, I'm getting the error `"Undefined Index: area"`

```
<select id="area" name="area" class="selectbox dropdownfilter" data-target-id="location">
    <option value="">all areas</option>
    <?php asort($areas) ?>
    <?php foreach ($areas as $code =>$area) : ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $code ?>"<?php if(isset($_SESSION['area']) | isset($_POST['area'])) { if($_SESSION['area'] == $area | $_POST['area'] == $area) { echo ' selected'; } } ?> ><?php echo $area ?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

It's outputting the `$area` correctly, the error is coming in the 'selected' script. Bit lost as to what I'm doing wrong, or how else I could do it. I'm just trying to select the option if it's what was submitted in the search form.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That condition:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['area']) | isset($_POST['area'])) {
```

=> Returns true if `$_SESSION['area']` is set OR `$_POST['area']` is set
So it is true if `$_SESSION['area']` is not set but `$_POST['area']` is set, for example.

Then :

```
    if($_SESSION['area'] == $area | $_POST['area'] == $area) {
```

=> You are testing `$_SESSION['area']` value. If it's not set (it's possible as seen before), you'll have an error notice.

Here is what I'd do, only one condition :

```
if (
    (isset($_SESSION['area']) && $_SESSION['area'] == $area)
    ||
    (isset($_POST['area']) && $_POST['area'] == $area)
) {
```

If `$_SESSION['area']` is not set, PHP won't bother to test if `$_SESSION['area'] == $area` because it doesn't need to (as the 1st condition is false anyway), it will try what is after the `OR`

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php
And http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: Great, thanks. Logic is not my strongpoint. Adding Ors into the mix doesn't help!

Answer (score 1):

The error "Undefined Index: area" means that *$_POST['area']* or *$_SESSION*['area'] is indeed set.... but the other one is not...

use this:

```
if((isset($_SESSION['area']) && $_SESSION['area'] == $area) || (isset($_POST['area']) && $_POST['area'] == $area)) {echo ' selected';}
```

or like this:

```
 if(@$_SESSION['area'] == $area || @$_POST['area'] == $area) {echo ' selected';}
```

Comment: Cheers. Only accepted the other answer as there was more explanation, but I'm using your script…

Comment: That gives me the error: "Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)"

Comment: it should not happen both codes are working. Before I corrected an error maybe you have the older version.... try again....

Comment: As suspected the issues were with my code. $_POST['area'] actually matches $code, not $area.